# PHP Test if Class Instance exists in an array Instances

Tags: php

I've got a Collection of closely related Objects. Before I add an Object to the collection, I want to check the class instance to make sure it's OK.

Normally, I like all my objects in a collection to have a similar baseClass OR interface so I can use type hinting but in this case, the objects aren't like that.

I like the way `instanceof` works. I don't want to have to manage a list of namespaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the new 5.4 [] for array() syntax - create an array of valid classnames:

```
private $validClasses = ['MyFirstClass','MySecondClass','MyThirdClass'];
```

Next, create a function to test.

```
public function testClass($class){
    $arr = explode("\\", get_class($class) );
    if ( !in_array( array_pop($arr) , $this->validClasses  ) ){
    throw new \Exception('Invalid Class - Cannot be added to the Collection.');
     }
}
```

Comment: Generates: "Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in ..."

Comment: This gives a Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference warning at `if ( !in_array( array_pop(explode("\\", get_class($class) ) ) , $this->validClasses  ) ){` (PHP 5.4.5)

Comment: I'm in 5.4.8 .. and I'm not getting that error and I'm using the code right now. with the Symfony2 Framework. No errors. But the code I'm using is not exactly what I pasted.. What would be causing this for you guys??

Comment: OK -- I found the strict issue. I'll be updating the answer soon.

Comment: The problem is highlighted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410061/only-variables-can-be-passed-by-reference-error). "You need to make the result of explode() a variable before you pass it on"